# NLP grouping word categories

Tags: nlp

Suppose I have a dictionary:

```
{apple:large apple, apple:red apple, apple:aple, orange:mandarin, orange:orang, orange:blood orange}
```

and so on...

And then I want to replace a large document of entries with the keys. However, occasionally a new value will come up, i.e. {apple:green apple}

Is there a method where I can replace all values with the corresponding key, but then also replace 'close' values like the one given if they appear?

Example document:

```
var1
_____
aple
apple
orange
Apple
Red apple
gren Apple
blood Orange
orang

var1_replaced
______________
apple
apple
orange
apple
apple
apple
orange
orange
```

Comment: Yes there is. Plz just clarify what "replace all values with the corresponding key" means? Can u update with a concrete example of input-output?

Comment: @KasraManshaei yes, like the example I added above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ... the simplest approach is using [Fuzzy String Matching](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) and it will work. Just go through the examples in python implementation of it ([fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy)) and you will understand how it works. You need to find a threshold by practice to determine if two strings are similar enough to be considered as same concept.

If it didn't work please drop a line in the comments so I can propose more sophisticated algorithms.

Good luck!